# Help with SBJSON + Facebook SDK Clash

Tags: iphone, json, facebook, sbjson

I was using the SBJSON files from [this JSON tutorial](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/json-framework-for-iphone-part-2.html) and then I tried using the Facebook iOS SDK. The Facebook SDK happens to have the same SBJSON files.. but apparently is a lot different. I cannot use both folder groups because I get "duplication errors" in Xcode. I tried removing the original JSON folder group, and now I get the following warnings: `SBJsonParser may not respond to objectWithString:error:` and a `SIGABRT` crash at this line: `return [jsonParser objectWithString:jsonString error:NULL];`

Anyone know how I can fix this? Thanks in advance!

```
// JSON from Server Actions
- (NSString *)stringWithUrl:(NSURL *)url {
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadRevalidatingCacheData
                                            timeoutInterval:30];
    // Fetch the JSON response
    NSData *urlData;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *error;

    // Make synchronous request
    urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                    returningResponse:&response
                                                error:&error];

    // Construct a String around the Data from the response
    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    }



- (id)objectWithUrl:(NSURL *)url {
    SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [SBJsonParser new];
    NSString *jsonString = [self stringWithUrl:url];

    // Parse the JSON into an Object
    return [jsonParser objectWithString:jsonString error:NULL];
    }

- (NSDictionary *)downloadManifest {
    id response = [self objectWithUrl:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/manifest.json"]];
    NSDictionary *feed = (NSDictionary *)response;
    return feed;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://nodeload.github.com/gabriel/yajl-objc/zipball/master

try with this parser...

Comment: Did you just end up using a new JSON parser because there was no solution? Switching the JSON library doesn't seem like a great solution IMHO.